# How to add the view_email_url url to my website as a link

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, view

I have a requirement to add a link to my website that will link to my exact target email (View as Webpage Link).

It looks like exact target generates a new **view_email_url** every time.

Can I just copy that url from the preview or is a way of generating the url.

Ex. http://view.exacttarget.com/?j=[]&m=[]&ls=[]&l=[]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's generated at send time.  Not sure you can build it manually, unless you can decipher the SFMC parameters. The parameters are send and subscriber specific.  Plus, the page is transient.  As soon as a subscriber in your sending List or Data Extension is gone, the page won't render.

Comment: You can make it somewhat permanent when you use Journey Builder as sending source. Because it creates Snapshots and persist them, thats one of the reasons why we use journey builder for sends. Because the view as email is implemented that it get crushed by any update on the sending dataextension.

Comment: True -- Triggered Send Definitions that originate in Journey Builder are associated with their own send log, basically.  They're not meant for bulk sends, however.  I've found that folks spend a log of time preserving VAWP and don't bother to evaluate how many subscribers are actually clicking on the link.  A high number of clicks may indicate rendering issues with the email.